# How can I open a new Scene from a different class

Tags: javafx

I have a simple button that i want to click and open a new scene but i made the new scene in another class but it doesn't work and it does not show my errors either.
Here is my Controller class

```
public class Controller
 {
  public TextField txtUsername;
  public TextField txtEmail;
  public TextField txtPass;
  public TextField txtPhone;
  public Button btnLogin;
 }
public void buttonClicked()
{
   Chattingform chattingform = new Chattingform ();
}
```

Here is my Chattingform class

```
public class Chattingform extends Application
{



@Override
public void start (Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {

    FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("Chattingform.fxml"));
    try {
        Parent root = fxmlLoader.load();
        Stage stage = new Stage();
        stage.initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL);
        stage.setOpacity(1);
        stage.setTitle("Exchat");
        stage.setScene(new Scene (root, 450, 450));
        stage.showAndWait();
    }catch ( IOException io )
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog (null, "Could not open ");
    }
}
```

Comment: The Initializable interface is what happens immediately ur app runs.  How will that help to open another scene when a button is clicked from another class

Answer (score 0):

**From my experince, all JavaFX Controllers have:**

```
@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
    // TODO
}
```